# Use an array item as replacement in a MATLAB regexpr

Tags: arrays, regex, matlab

I have a string containing a math function like this:

```
sin(x[1]) + cos(x[2]) + tan(x[3]) + x[1]
```

Now I want to replace each x[number] with a letter of the alphabet using regexpr. The result should look like this:

```
sin(a) + cos(b) + tan(c) + a
```

So I defined an alphabet array like this:

```
alphabet = ('a':'z')
```

This is my first regexpr that just replaces every x[number] with an 'a':

```
regexprep(functionString,'x\[(\d+)\]','${alphabet(1)}');
```

What I tried to make it replace with the right letter, is using $1 instead of 1. I thought this would not use alphabet(1) but dynamically the item at the right alphabet index.

```
regexprep(functionString,'x\[(\d+)\]','${alphabet($1)}');
```

Instead I am getting an error that the index exceeds the matrix dimensions.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? How do I get the right letter?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matlab uses the `$1` input as text. Since `int32('1') = 49` you result with an error `Index exceeds matrix dimensions`.

To solve your issue, use `str2num`:

```
regexprep(functionString,'x\[(\d+)\]','${alphabet(str2num($1))}')
```

Comment: That works! But I have no idea why. Can you explain what (49:74) does? Thank you!

Comment: Added explanation

Answer (score 1):

In case you're interested, you can actually do this without having to create an `alphabet` variable. Here's how:

```
regexprep(functionString,'x\[(\d+)\]','${char($1+48)}')
```

Adding 48 to your index `$1` and converting it to a [`char`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html) will give you ASCII characters starting at `'a'`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `regexprep(functionString,'x\[(\d+)\]','${alphabet($0)}');`?

From what I see here : https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html regex matches are 0 based, so the first one should be $0.

Comment: Just tried it: $0 returns the whole match x[2]. $1 returns 2. So using alphabet($1) sounds more logic. But still there is the error.